# Coding oldschool textCaptcha nowadays is good idea?

Tags: php, gd, captcha, self-hosting

I am creating my own tool related to GDPR (https://my.oodo.pl) and recently, taking into account privacy doubts related to GA, reCaptcha (i was using recaptcha V3), Google Fonts (Schrems II), I decided to self-host everything I can and create my own solutions. So far i installed my own statistics solution, and my own cookie manager, minimizing cookies to my own.

Currently, I am creating an old-school captcha tool from scratch and probably from looking at and refreshing the page for the thousandth time I am not sure if these text deformations are not too big.

Can you check the test images? Can You read it? Isn't that frustrating? Is it worth going for such a solution nowadays?
In final solution should I ask users for letters, words, phrases or maybe some more sofisticated solutions (like printing one string "catdogfish" and asking for first word letters)? Maybe you have any ideas?

Im using PHP GD library with some simple deformations and transitions iterations. Do You know any sites with some advanced GD examples?

Here are the links to the test images - refreshing will give u new random captcha:
https://dev.oodo.pl/test01.php

https://dev.oodo.pl/test010.php

https://dev.oodo.pl/test02.php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Meantime i found interesting article about captcha technology. Its from 2023:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050923002296?via%3Dihub